# Given H3 cells from polyfill, how to identify cells which are fully contained, partially contained or contiguous with the polygon?

Tags: python-3.x, h3

As mentioned in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62519680/18792265) on how to identify hexagons which overlap, i am confused as to how we can identify fully contained, partially contained or contiguous cells of a polygon (check if it intersects the polygon).

Answer (score 0):

Refining the H3 `polyfill` output is generally a two-step process:

1. If needed, buffer the `polyfill` output to include cells that might match your chosen criteria but do not have a center inside the polygon. This is necessary for partially contained or contiguous cases. The buffering operation can be performed by taking `kRing(cell, 1)` for every cell and adding the output to a new set (e.g. in JS: `Set(cells.flatMap(cell => kRing(cell, 1)))`).
2. Filter the set of cells by your chosen criteria. This might require an external spatial library with functions like `touches` or `intersects`, or you might need to implement these yourself. Generally you would take the boundary of each cell and compare to your polygon, e.g.

```
cells.filter(cell => intersects(h3ToGeoBoundary(cell), myPolygon)))
```